# Correct place for "constitutes"

Tags: grammaticality

> Substantial progress has been made in the last years in order to answer the question what an optimal strategy for this network constitutes.
>
> Substantial progress has been made in the last years in order to answer the question, what constitutes an optimal strategy for this network.

Which sentence should I use, the first or the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *second* example is correct. The first isn't a valid sentence.

However, I do suggest that in general it might be better to stick with words you *do* know how to use. I have the impression you want your sentence to sound knowledgeable, professional, and impressive. But don't forget the main purpose of most communication is to convey the primary meaning itself, not secondary impressions about the status of the writer.

Having said that, you don't want *in the last years*. It should be *in recent years*.

Comment: Just for clarification. Is it _wrong_ to use _in the last years_ or just bad style? And why?

Comment: @Christian: In your context, it's wrong. You could say *in the last years of Queen Victoria's reign*, for example (though *final years* would be much preferred). But where the time-frame is relative to implicit but non-specified "today", you can't really get away with that.